# Campy 11 speed and Shimano compatibility

Tags: derailleur

Two part question.

Is it possible to run Chorus, Record or Super Record 11 speed disc mechanical brake/shifters with Ultegra R8000 11 speed derailleurs?

I can use either campy or Shimano wheels and cassettes.

Are Campy brake levers going to work with Ultegra disk brake?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't point to documentation, but I'm pretty sure Campagnolo uses a different derailleur actuation ratio to Shimano.

Comment: For commercial reasons the parts are not meant to be compatible. Even though the differences are tiny they will prevent harmonious combinations.

Comment: I have discovered they additional research that The pull ratio of campy 11 and Ultegra R8000 is .01mm difference and the sprocket pitch is the same.i figured that being such a minuscule difference, that somebody could have made it work.   
If anyone has additional experiences, please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Derailleurs: No. Shimano and Campagnolo derailleurs have different actuation ratios, and while there are adapters for many other combinations, Shimano to Campagnolo 11-speed isn't manufactured. The cassettes are so close that you can use cassette from one 11-speed system with the other, so there's less need to mix derailleur brands.

Mechanical brakes: Yes, but not optimal. Newer Shimano road brakes use slightly more cable movement for the same brake actuation, so Campagnolo levers will work with them but feel spongy and if you don't keep the brakes well adjusted the levers may hit handlebars before maximum braking power.

Hydraulic brakes: From what I could find, both brands use 22mm pistons, 5mm hoses and mineral oil based brake fluid, so they are not fundamentally incompatible. I wouldn't try it myself, since brakes are the one component you don't want to fail.

Edit: Regarding the other answer, the fluid transfer amount is determined only by piston cross section area. Shimano and Campagnolo road brakes apparently have similar sized pistons, but this doesn't apply MTB models, different brands and future models. The fittings are different, but since hose size is same, you should be able to install fitting from different brand on one end. I still wouldn't do this and shifting wouldn't still work.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that strikes me about your question is the fact that the Ultegra disc brake is hydraulic as there is no road mechanical disc brake caliper at the Ultegra level.  As such, one cannot mix brands of hydraulic brake levers and hydraulic calipers.  Although both Shimano and Campy use mineral oil, the specs of the hose and it's fittings differ between these brands.  More critically, the amount and rate of fluid transfer from the master cylinders (within the levers) varies such that the opposing brand's caliper response is goofed up. So, a Campy brake lever would be incompatible for an Ultegra disc brake caliper.

In the first part of your question, I've decided that your use of the word, "mechanical," refers only to the shifting aspect and not the braking, which if we're looking at the same systems in both parts of your question, remains hydraulic.  As an aside, Shimano and Campagnolo's electronic shift systems are incompatible between one's shifter and the other's derailleurs due to wiring and battery differences.  I doubt the software would play well together sans hacking ability of the user.

Strictly speaking, there is incompatibility if one wants to mix Campy & Shimano shifters with the other's derailleurs. This is due to differing cable pull ratios between brands of shifters.  Also complicating things is Campy's use of variable spacing between cassette sprockets. At the 11 speed level the differences at the cassette are minor enough that one can use a Campy cassette with a Shimano shifter/derailleur with only a small reduction in shift quality. Mixing the brands' shifter and derailleur however would create a situation where the rear derailleur would move incorrect distances in relation to the sprocket spacing and cause noise, ghost shifting, no shifting or over shifting.  Apparently a company called [J-tek makes a product called shiftmate](http://www.jtekengineering.com/shiftmate/shiftmate-compatibility-charts-choices/) which corrects the mixed brands' shifting incompatibility by altering the amount of cable pull that reaches the derailleur.   However, the bad news comes at the end of that long list of combinations possible with a J-tek Shiftmate I've linked to above when they note in their comments under Shiftmate X, subheading, Campagnolo 11 speed shifter with Shimano 11 speed road or mountain derailleur: "CAN'T BE DONE."

Anyway, in researching this answer, I came across this [Article on mixing road bike components](https://cyclingtips.com/2017/12/mixing-road-groupsets-what-works-together-and-what-doesnt-2/).  It's a pretty clear summary of what's known about the effects of mixing components from different groupsets, not only from competing brands, but also various models within the same brand.